# How to extract text from website to textview using jsoup?

Tags: android, text, textview, jsoup

Hello everyone Im creating now a webscraping app. I watch a youtube video on how to make it, and this is what I got but its not working. Please correct this code

```
   try 
    { 
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect
        ("https://elegant-jones-f4e94a.netlify.com/valid_doc.html").get();
        
         String title = doc.title(); 
         } catch 
    
    (Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println(title);
         }
    
    
    textview1.setText(title);
```

Comment: make sure you have internet permission added in your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this example

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Log.d("abc",doc.title());
String body = doc.body().text(); 
Log.d("abc","html body text "+body);
```

For more examples you can refer [jsoup cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/) and [this website](https://aboullaite.me/jsoup-html-parser-tutorial-examples/)

Comment: Then how to put the text to textview? sorry Im very new on webscrapping

Comment: just use settext method of textview and pass this body text to it.. e.g yourtextview.setText(body);